# Submit button not working in internet exlorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, niceforms

I have a login page which works perfectly in Firefox,but it is not working in Internet explorer on the server.The form is not submitted.Also,I'm using niceform template.What could be the problem? My form code

```
            <form action="myurl"
                method="post" class="niceform">

                <fieldset>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>
                            <label for="email">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Username:</label>
                        </dt>
                        <dd>
                            <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" size="54" />
                            <font color="red"></font>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>
                            <label for="password">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Password:</label>

                        </dt>
                        <dd>
                            <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" size="54" />
                            <font color="red" > </font>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>
                            <label for="password">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Login As:</label>
                        </dt>                       
                        <dd>
                            <select name="user_type">
                            <option value="user"> User </option>

                            </select>

                        <font color="red">
                            <span id="login_err" style="display: none;"> username or password can not be left blank.</span><br />
                                                            </font>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl class="submit" style="text-align: right;">
                        <p style="padding-left: 91px; float: right; padding-right: 59px; width: 128px; font-weight: bold;">

                                                                                                &nbsp;
                        </p>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enter" />

                    </dl>

                </fieldset>

            </form>
```

My Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var username = $.trim($('#username').val());
        var password = $.trim($('#username').val());

        if(username== ''||username == null|| password=='' || password == null ){
            $('#login_err').show();
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you need to include all relevant (read form) html and possible validation scripts etc

Comment: What does the form look like?  Any events bound to the form?

Comment: yes there are a few custom form validations and from there i'm returning true or false.

Comment: please check now i have updated my question.

Comment: Are there errors in the console by any chance?

Comment: There is a 404 error regarding an image and i don't thing it will be troubling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys it wasn't the issue of submit.The page was redirected in the serverside code giving it an illusion that the form was never submitted. 

The issue was with internet explorer catching.There was some issue with naming convention of the cookie and it was not storing the user data in the session and therefore the user was redirected to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Submit button will not work alone. You need proper `<form>` around it like this:

```
<form method="post" action="myscript.php">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>
```

It should work now.

Comment: he said that it works at firefox though? So there must be form already? :)

Comment: @MaunoV. afair forms without `action` worked with FF as well, so who knows what else lurks there.

Comment: Maybe temporarily disable Javascript to see if it's a script problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name and id of the submit button. Sometimes browsers have key words and i think '**Submit**' is a keyword and may be there is some conflict. Not sure whether this is going to work but its worth a try.